# Reference not showing all names

Tags: biblatex, author-number

When I cite a paper in the main text with more than 2 authors I want biblatex to add et al. This is happening but at the end of the document in References only one author is shown with et al.

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,dashed=false,natbib=true,url=true,bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}
```

This is what I get

[image]

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `minbibnames` and `maxbibnames`.  (page 47, biblatex.pdf)

Example:

```
\usepackage[minbibnames=1, maxbibnames=99, backend=biber,style=authoryear,dashed=false,natbib=true,url=true,bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}
```